# Binary search tree left rotation

Tags: c++, data-structures, rotation, binary-search-tree

I'm going over rotations and trying to rotate courses that have been to my binary search tree to the left or right depending on what method I call. There is a bug somewhere in my code and I think I've isolated it to the rotation method since everytime I try to print after I successfully do a rotation, it goes into an infinite loop. Is there some type of pointer or call mixup in my method? I feel that my logic is right but can't seem to figure out where the bug is(or even if it's in this method).

Here's my left rotation method:

```
bool BinarySearchTree::leftRotate(string number)
{
Course *x, *y;

if (treeSearch(number) == NULL){
    return false;
}
else{
    x = treeSearch(number);
}

if (x->getRight() == NULL){
    return false;
}
else{
    y = x->getRight();
    x->setRight(y->getLeft());
}

if (y->getLeft() != NULL){
    y->getLeft()->setParent(x);
}
y->getParent()->setParent(x);

if(x->getParent() == NULL){
    root = y;
}
else if( x->getParent()->getRight() == x){
    x->getParent()->setLeft(y);
}
else{
    x->getParent()->setRight(y);
}
    y->setLeft(x);
    x->setParent(y);
return true; 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with the smallest data-set that causes the bug to appear, and then step through the code line by line in a debugger. That should hopefully help you at least narrow it down to a few lines of problematic code.

Comment: Providing the code for struct/class Course could be a good idea.

Comment: So it shows that the bug happens right at y->setLeft(x); on the third to last line. I'm not sure why that is though.

Comment: The line `y->getParent()->setParent(x);`seems strange to me. y is right of x. So the parent of y must be x. If that is correct then the code is `x->setParent(x)`. But maybe I'm wrong here. The data structure would help.

Comment: Would the insert function help you for understanding how we insert each node in the tree? Sorry just not sure exactly what part of the code you want to see

Comment: @Slae : I assume that `Course` is a class with 3 `Course*`members (pLeft, pRight, pParent) and a `string mNumber`. I guess the `treeSearch` finds a node in the tree where `mNumber` equals `number`. If that is not correct then provide the code for `class Course`. But read my comment above - I think it pinpoints the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems as if

```
y->getParent()->setParent(x);
```

should be

```
y->setParent(x->getParent());
```

But do it after checking for x->getParent being NULL.

Something like

```
// Remove this line: y->getParent()->setParent(x);

if(x->getParent() == NULL){
    root = y;
}
else if( x->getParent()->getRight() == x){
    y->setParent(x->getParent());   // Insert this line
    x->getParent()->setLeft(y);
}
```

EDIT:
After looking at the code again, I think y->setParent(x->getParent()) shall be called even when x->getParent() returns NULL. The reason is that if y becomes the new root, y shall also have Parent set to NULL.

So the code below is likely a better answer:

```
// Remove this line: y->getParent()->setParent(x);

y->setParent(x->getParent());   // Insert this line

if(x->getParent() == NULL){
    root = y;
}
else if( x->getParent()->getRight() == x){
    x->getParent()->setLeft(y);
}
```